# Getting exception suddenly from entityframework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-identity, azure-sql-database

I get this exception from time to time :

> The 'Email' property on 'User' could not be set to a 'System.Int64' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.String'.  Method Message:, LogException: System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Email' property on 'User' could not be set to a 'System.Int64' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.String'. 
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at Project.Services.UserService.FindById(Int64 userId)

I'm using Asp.net Identity in MVC project.

My User class like :

```
public class User : IdentityUser<long, IdentityConfig.UserLogin, IdentityConfig.UserRole, IdentityConfig.UserClaim>
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(IdentityConfig.CustomUserManager manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    [MaxLength(256)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [Required]
    public override string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

      // rest of properties
    ....
}
```

UserManager :

```
public class CustomUserManager : UserManager<User, long>
    {
        public CustomUserManager(IUserStore<User, long> store, IdentityFactoryOptions<CustomUserManager> options) : base(store)
        {
            this.UserValidator = new UserValidator<User, long>(this)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 8,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
                RequireDigit = true
            };

            // Configure user lockout defaults
            UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
            DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

            // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
            // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
            RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Google Authentication", new GoogleAuthenticatorTokenProvider());

            var provider = new MachineKeyProtectionProvider();
            UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User,long>(provider.Create("ResetPasswordPurpose"));

        }
    }
```

UserService:

```
public class UserService : EntityService<User>, IUserService
   {
    private readonly IdentityConfig.CustomUserManager _userManager;

    public UserService(MyDbContext context, IdentityConfig.CustomUserManager userManager) : base(context)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

   public User FindById(long userId)
    {
        return _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == userId);
    }

// other methods..
}
```

Register Autofac:

```
        builder.RegisterModule(new ServiceModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new EfModule());

        builder.RegisterType<IdentityConfig.RoleStore>().As<IRoleStore<IdentityConfig.Role, long>>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<IdentityConfig.CustomUserStore>().As<IUserStore<User, long>>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<IdentityConfig.CustomUserManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<IdentityConfig.CustomSignInManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<IdentityConfig.CustomRoleManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();

        builder.Register<IAuthenticationManager>(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);


        builder.Register(c => new IdentityFactoryOptions<IdentityConfig.CustomUserManager>
        {
            DataProtectionProvider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("MyWebAppName"),
            Provider = new IdentityFactoryProvider<IdentityConfig.CustomUserManager>()
        }).InstancePerRequest();



public class ServiceModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Project.Services"))

                 .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service") || t.Name.EndsWith("Validator"))
                 .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                 .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}


 public class EfModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType(typeof(MyDbContext)).AsSelf().WithParameter("connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString).InstancePerRequest();
    }
}
```

What I noticed also is this error affect some of other entities not just the user !

The problem is the application runs for some time and then gives this kind of errors too much, which does not make any sense to me and makes me mad.

I'm using Azure SQL , Azure web services, Autofac.

Comment: could be your cookie becomes garbage at some point, or you have a threading issue where it's reading and writing the cookie simultaneously

Comment: I don't see any exception handling ... and you are using async / await.  What are you expecting the method to do, and where does the exception get thrown?

Comment: @DanEsparza I posted the whole exception

Comment: Problems occurring when *the application runs for some time* are usually related to EF context instances living too long and being used in multiple threads (requests). So what's a regular context life cycle in your app?

Comment: @GertArnold I updated my code, I also suspect on EF context but I tried to register it with different type of registration in autofac.

Comment: If you were able to repro this immediately, I would suspect of a mapping issue: this exception would occur if the schema in the DbDataReader does not match what EF expects. But since the application "runs for some time", I agree with others that this could be a threading issue in the application. EF is not thread safe: context instances should only be accessed by one thread at the time. In terms of ASP.NET, that means having the lifetime of the context be associated with each individual web request, avoiding Tasks that are not awaited in your code, avoiding code that spawns new threads, etc.

Comment: @MohamedFarrag did you fix this issue?

Comment: @DavideLettieri No Davide I still receive it specially when we have a lot of requests.

Comment: @MohamedFarrag I'm experiencing the same issue but with EF 6.4 + ASP.NET Core + Azure SQL. Did you manage to find a fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. It happens on medium to high demand. I don't know what to do anymore. I'm recycling 5x/day.

I couldn't find any standard. The exception throws in many different methods. No standard. Looks completely random.

It seems that i'm trying to retrieve an information on DB and it always returns blank data, so an error is thrown when it tries to cast the null data to the model.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30387471)

Comment: My plan was just add a comment, but SOF doesn`t allowed me by lack of reputation :(